# Listando após select de um autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui

Olá, minha dúvida é:

Ao fazer um `select` em alguma das opções do `autocomplete`, deve mostrar o conteúdo na página.

Ao limpar os dados inseridos no `input`, a página volta ao estado anterior.

Ou seja, ao selecionar, ele abrirá o que foi selecionado, e ao limpar o campo do `input`, mostrará os tópicos anteriores.

segue abaixo meus códigos:

HTML:

```html
<form class="submit-line" id="form">

      <input  id="buscaPerguntas" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-faq" placeholder="Digite palavras-chaves para pesquisar" style="padding: 28px;">

</form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="buscaPerguntas-description">
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="divFaq" id="listaFaq">
            <div class="row">
                {% for valor in faq%}

                <div class="col-sm-12">

                    <div class="boxFaq">
                        <a class="btn btn-faq accordion" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{valor.id}}" aria-expanded="true">
                             {{valor.pergunta}}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div id="{{valor.id}}" class="collapse">
                        <div class="boxFaq">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div>{{valor.resposta|raw}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}

            </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $("#buscaPerguntas").autocomplete({

        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 1,
        appendTo: '#form',
        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/pesquisafaq',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    dadosPesquisa: request.term

                }


            }).done(function (data) {

                let parse = JSON.parse(data)

                if (parse.length > 0) {

                    let dados = Object.values(parse).map((e) => {

                        return {
                            label: e.pergunta,
                            desc: "<div class='divFaqCollapse'><div class='col-sm-12'><div class='boxFaq'><a class='btn btn-faq accordion' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse' aria-expanded='true'>" + e.pergunta + "</a></div></div> <div class='col-sm-12'> <div id='collapse' class='collapse'> <div class='boxFaq'> <div class='card-body'> <div>" + e.resposta + "</div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>",

                        }

                    })
                    response(dados.slice(0))
                }


            });

        },
        select: function (event, ui) {

            $("#buscaPerguntas").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#buscaPerguntas-description").html(ui.item.desc);


            $('#listaFaq').hide();
            $('#buscaPerguntas-description').show();

        }

    })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

já que ninguém nunca me responde... consegui resolver o problema e decidi compartilhar pois talvez possa ser a mesma dúvida de outras pessoas.

eu só precisei validar o que estava chegando no input e de lá mostrava o contéudo que eu queria...

o meu JS ficou assim:

```
$(function () {
$("#buscaPerguntas").autocomplete({

    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 1,
    appendTo: '#form',
    source: function (request, response) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/pesquisafaq',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                dadosPesquisa: request.term

            }


        }).done(function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            let parse = JSON.parse(data)

            if (parse.length > 0) {


                let dados = Object.values(parse).map((e) => {

                    return {
                        label: e.pergunta,
                        desc: "<div class='divFaqCollapse'><div class='col-sm-12'><div class='boxFaq'><a class='btn btn-faq accordion' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse' aria-expanded='true'>" + e.pergunta + "</a></div></div> <div class='col-sm-12'> <div id='collapse' class='collapse'> <div class='boxFaq'> <div class='card-body'> <div>" + e.resposta + "</div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>",

                    }

                })
                response(dados.slice(0))
            }


        });


    },
    select: function (event, ui) {

                $("#listaFaq").hide();
                $("#buscaPerguntas-description").html(ui.item.desc).show();


        $('#form').keyup(function () {
            $('#buscaPerguntas').each(function () {

                if (this.value == '') {
                    $("#listaFaq").show();
                    $("#buscaPerguntas-description").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#buscaPerguntas-description").html(ui.item.desc).show();
                    $("#listaFaq").hide();

                    //  $("#buscaPerguntas").val(ui.item.label);

                }




            });

        });


    }



});
```